# Quickest Way to Import Matrix

Tags: python, readfile, large-files

Currently, I am reading a 10,000 x 10,000 txt matrix (seperated by spaces) into a python program using the sys.argv method. It seems to take too long. What is the most efficient way to read the matrix into the program?

Comment: You just made up a thing called the sys.argv method. I don't think anyone else knows what that means.

Comment: Can you show us the code, what you're trying so far and a sample input you're providing it? Is it `python test.py 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... etc..`? Are you ensuring that you have 100000000 numbers sent as arguments? Did you try putting them into a file instead?